# Ignore a file when merging -- but include it in pushes

Tags: git

I have a django project and I'm using git.

I need to have different settings.py file, for each branch.

I've tested add settings.py to .gitattributes with merge=ours, but it not worked because if it's not having any conflict Git will merge normally.

Also, add settings.py to .gitignore is not an option, cause if I change something in the settings.py, I want it pushed to the same branch.

Is there a way to ignore a file when merging but still push it?

UPDATE:

I've tried VonC's solution and I've created two settings: settings_production.py and settings_development.py.

So, I pip installed gitpython and used it in my settings.py, like this:

```
from git import Repo
import os

r = Repo(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
if r.active_branch.__str__( == 'master':
    from settings_production.py import *
else:
    from settings_development.py import *
```

And it worked fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Branching: different config files for release/development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636492/branching-different-config-files-for-release-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer having versioned:

- a template file `settings.py.tpl`
- a value file per branch: `settings.py.branch1` in `branch1`, `settings.py.branch2` in `branch2`, ... (meaning, no merge issue ever: each value file remains untouched)
- a script able to detect the current branch, take the right value file and build from the template file the final `settings.py` (which is private to your working tree: it is never versioned)

That script can be automatically called through a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309) which will, on checkout, build the right config file.

[image: smudge]

A [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) can register that '`smudge`' script for the `settings.py.*` files.
(no need for a '`clean`' script on checkin)

Answer (score 0):

It's either VonC's solution, or you make your settings.py file where you check which branch it is in and import branch specific code from a `settings-branchX.py`. This solution's pretty close to VonC's, but you're doing it in python, and not messing up with git.

You may get inspiration from that [gist](https://gist.github.com/igniteflow/1760854).