# Different configs in each git branch

Tags: git, travis-ci

I have two git branches: `dev` and `master`

I'm using Travis CI for builds and testing and need to have different `.travis.yml` and `config.yml.enc` (encrypted config file) for each branch/environment.

How do I merge changes from `dev->master` without merging the `.travis.yml` and `config.yml.enc` files?

Comment: Can't you do the merge with `--no-commit`, explicitly checkout the master's .travis.yml file, and then commit the merge?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636492/branching-different-config-files-for-release-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options here (on master branch):

You can either run:

```
git merge --no-commit dev

git checkout .travis.yml

git checkout config.yml.end

git commit -m "merge dev into master"
```

This will merge the files then revert the two files to the last master commit.

Or you can run (if your commit history is setup this way):

```
git cherry-pick commit_hash
```

Adding commits where the files are not modified.

Comment: This could work but in terms to automating the process, this isn't a very practical solution.