# What is the right way of keeping files with same names but different content intact locally and on remote server during push and pull in git?

Tags: git, push, gitignore, pull

I need to keep separate configuration.php files locally and on server.

The problem is
I've added the file to .gitignore and removed it from index using `git rm --cached configuration.php`
but then when I push it server, it deletes configuration.php from server.

I am not sure how `-assume-unchanged` works.

What would be the correct solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Branching: different config files for release/development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636492/branching-different-config-files-for-release-development) and a bazillion others

Comment: @meagar what you suggest is slightly different and not clear enough. I dont want to push config files but if i add them on my local `gitignore`... push deletes config files on server... how to solve that? for all machines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` instead of `git rm --cached` if the `configuration.php` is not changed and pushed to git server frequently but only different in different clients.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged configuration.php
```

From [doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index),

> This option can be also used as a coarse file-level mechanism to
>   **ignore uncommitted changes in tracked files** (akin to what .gitignore
>   does for untracked files).

The only problem is that if others push new changes of `configuration.php` to the git server, you need to manually handle it if you do `git pull`.